# Webpack: Module parse failed

Tags: webpack, babeljs

Running the following web pack config gives me tons of errors, the first one is beneath. I just dont understand why it is within web pack itself.

Note; I am using Reactjs.

Update: When I do `webpack` and not `webpack web pack.config.js` it works. But I need to be able to use one for production and one for development?

Do you know why ?

webpack config: webpack.condig.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/main.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/app/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/, loader: 'babel', include: path.join(__dirname, 'app')},
      { test: /\.js?$/, exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/, loader: 'babel', include: path.join(__dirname, 'app')},
      { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file-loader" },
      { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
    ]
  }
};
```

Error:

```
ERROR in (webpack)/package.json
Module parse failed: src/node_modules/webpack/package.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "name": "webpack",
|   "version": "1.12.1",
|   "author": {
 @ (webpack)/lib/Stats.js 139:16-42
```

Comment: are you trying to load Json file without a json-loader?

Comment: How are you running webpack (command line command)?

Comment: Nope, but I am using Reactjs?

Comment: Yes. I am doing: webpack webpack.config.json

Comment: Sorry nils, I do have the config file as a .js file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [webpack documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html) it states:

> If you use the CLI it will read a file `webpack.config.js` (or the file passed by the --config option). This file should export the configuration object:

So webpack is looking for a `.js` file, not a `.json` (besides the fact that the content of your file is also JS). Rename your `webpack.config.json` to `webpack.config.js`, then you can just call it like this:

```
webpack
```

If you want to load it via the command line and another filename for the config file, you could also do it like this:

```
webpack --config yourconfig.js
```

Comment: Very simpel: I was missing --config ;-)